# How to make a menu list for a selected option?

Tags: javascript, html

All I want is when the user choose the 1. option then the menu list or option list for 1. option shows and the same like the other one.  For example if an user choose LOL then the option list for LOL shows up

```
<body>   
<form id="Game">
<fieldset> <legend> Vælg Øl Type: </legend>
    <input type="radio" name="LOL " value= "LOL" checked> LOL
    <input type="radio" name= "OW" value="OW"  checked>  OW
    <input type="radio" name="DOTA2"" value="DOTA2"  checked>  DOTA2
   <select> 
    <option value ="">1</option>
    <option value ="">2</option>
</select>
    <input type="button" value="Start">
```

Comment: What is a "menu list"?

Comment: @ChrisG a select option

Comment: Are you asking how to show a dynamic second <select> depending on which option the user has chosen?

Comment: @ChrisG Exactly thats what  I meant

Comment: Right, the answer is to a) attach an `onchange` event listener to the <select> b) create/change HTML elements dynamically. Both these separate problems have loads of existing answers all over the internet. I also suspect that this specific problem has a bunch of duplicates right here on SO, for instance this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23453989/changing-2nd-dropdown-options-based-on-first-dropdown-choicejavascript-only

Comment: @ChrisG  The problem is  I use radio button, how can show the select option depends on the selected radio button?